# How Do I remove left hand Navigation?

Tags: sharepoint-online

in sharepoint online in a site, there is a left hand navigation, is there a way of removing it[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.google.nl/search?q=remove+left+navigation

But your screenshot look like the Modern Experience,
and Microsoft has disabled all CSS Branding or use of JavaScript on the Modern Experience

http://sympmarc.com/2016/06/16/dear-microsoft-please-listen-to-us-about-the-new-document-library-experience/